# Setting the default tab when using storyboards

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar

Can anyone please tell me how to set the default tab when using storyboards in iOS. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by default tab? Are you using tabBarController and trying to select the first tab when your app launches??

Comment: please make sure your question is descriptive and improve your accepted rate too..

Comment: I created a Tabbed Application using story boards and I want to set it so that the second tab is selected when the app launches.

Comment: create a property for your tabBarController in your appdelegate and select the index 1 of your tabbar item in your applicationDidFinishLaunching: method. add like this.[tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedItem:1];

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use one of these two methods:

```
tabBar.items = tabBarItems;
tabBar.selectedItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0];
```

or a direct method from the object

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:myUITabBarItem];
```

or you can combine them to do this:

```
tabBar.items = tabBarItems;
[tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0]];
```

but i havent tested that method yet, hope this helps!

Comment: How can I create the outlet property for the tabbar controller?please let me know as I am new to storyboard

Comment: yea, i personaly suck at story boarding, i can send you some code if you want?

Comment: let me try to find the exact code and put it up on pastebin, otherwise ill zip it and out it on my website

Comment: This is a great answer to a different question

Comment: As for Swift 5 (Xcode 10.2) this happens to be no longer allowed: `Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.`. The subclassing solution from @Aviel Gross is still working: `selectedIndex = defaultIndex`

Answer (score 126):

Whilst you can set the initial selected tab programmatically like the other answers, to achieve the same in your storyboard without touching code you would perform the following:

1. Select the Tab Bar Controller in the Storyboard Interface
2. Show the Identity Inspector in the Utilities panel
3. Add a new "User Defined Runtime Attribute"
4. Set the Key Path to "selectedIndex"
5. Set the Type to "Number"
6. Set the Value to the index of the tab you wish to select (a value of 1 would select the second tab for example)
7. Save the Storyboard, build and run the application

This should be what it looks like when you've achieved the above steps:

[image]

Comment: This still works for me on Xcode 6.3.1, iOS 8.3 - any further details on the issue you're having Jason?

Comment: Likely weirdness on my end in that case; it's a crash at `_NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter`: http://pastie.org/10185899

Comment: These instructions worked for me, without the subclass. (iOS8.3/Xcode6.3.1)

Comment: Doesn't work for me neither. Xcode 7.2. Error I get is: Failed to set (selectedIndex) user defined inspected property on (UITabBarController): Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/...

Comment: Works like a charm, make sure you use it on the UITabBarController not the UITabBar or any nested UIViweController.

Comment: worked great for me, very interesting how that works.

Comment: Doesn't work on Xcode 7.3. Error `Failed to set (selectedIndex) user defined inspected property on (UITabBarController): Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/...`

Comment: I think this works only if you have a .xib file. It does not have anything to do with Xcode version.

Comment: Be careful doing this because accessing a ViewControllers attribute/view this way will cause a pre-emptive call of viewDidLoad. Just something to keep in mind. Otherwise this is definitely the cleanest way

Comment: This simply does NOT WORK. "Failed to set (selectedIndex) user defined inspected property"

Answer (score 78):

Might seem like overkill for some to subclass `UITabBarController`, but, I think it provides the cleanest solution.

1. Create `BaseTabBarController.swift`
2. Add an `@IBInspectable` and set it in `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   class BaseTabBarController: UITabBarController {

       @IBInspectable var defaultIndex: Int = 0

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           selectedIndex = defaultIndex
       }

   }
   ```
3. In the storyboard, set you `UITabBarController` to be your new subclass:

[image]

4. Go to the *Attributes Inspector* add set the new property **Default Index**:

[image]

5. ta-da! (:

Comment: Actually a fantastic solution for re-usability, and flexible enough still to allow it to be managed in code if required.

Comment: Fantastic solution @Aviel. Thank you.

Comment: Annnd BOOM! There goes the dynamite - this worked (Xcode 7.3.1). Thanks

Comment: This works great, I just had to do a clean & rebuild before the change was loaded onto the device but other than that it's a clean, quick, and intuitive solution.

Comment: Great !!@Aviel Gross You nailed it!!

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Answer (score 36):

1. Create a new file subclass of `UITabBarController`;
2. Add this at the end of `viewDidLoad`:

   `self.selectedIndex = 1;`
3. Set this new file as the Custom Class in the `UITabBarController` of your Storyboard.

You're done.

Answer (score 24):

The following code worked for me:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: This code assumes that rootViewController is the tabBarController. Which might not always be true.

Answer (score 4):

in appdelegate find `applicationDidBecomeActive` function and add this lines

```
let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 // any index you want
```

Comment: How do you know that the rootViewController is  always the tabBarController?

Comment: When we are using the tab bar, by default the tabBarController is the rootViewController. Unless otherwise you changed the rootViewController after initiallization

Comment: I did it in 'SceneDelegate' in 'willConnectTo' method, where I'm setting rootViewController, and worked.

Answer (score 3):

My variant is suitable when you want **just change the default selected controller**, no more customizing. Just add the follow **category**:

```
//  UITabBarController+DefaultPage.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITabBarController(DefaultPage)

@end


//  UITabBarController+DefaultPage.m
#import "UITabBarController+DefaultPage.h"

@implementation UITabBarController(DefaultPage)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedIndex = 1;
}

@end
```

p.s: I prefer @joshua-finch [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27994209/1067147)

Answer (score 2):

In the `viewDidLoad()` of the `TabBarController`, set `selectedIndex` to whatever you want. (`0` would be the first, `3` would be the fourth, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through Xcode 8 or later (just tested it and don't know if it's available before this version)

Do the steps as @Joshua Finch said but:

1. Select the bar item instead of the TabBar
2. Got to "User Defined Runtime Attribute"
3. Add new key
4. Name it "selected"
5. Set its type to boolean and choose true / or check the checkbox

Comment: "xcode 8 or before": did you really mean "before"? It seems to contradict the following sentence, "dunno if its available before this version". Maybe you meant "8 or greater"?

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Aviel Gross' answer, I just wanted to implement this for a UITabBar, as opposed to a UITabBarController. This can be done as follows:

```
class BaseTabBar: UITabBar {

    @IBInspectable var defaultIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.selectedItem = self.items?[defaultIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're navigating to your UITabBarController from e.g. a login screen it might be least pain to set the selection there:

```
        let tabs = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabs") as! UITabBarController
        tabs.selectedIndex = 1
        self.present(tabs, animated:false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In InterfaceBuilder, disconnect all the segues, then reconnect them in the order you want them to appear.