# tab bar select index in swift

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, tabs

I am trying to make one of my tabs to be the first screen to show on the start of the app 
I have 5 view controllers embeded with navigation controllers

how can I choose any of the tabs to start on the view did load ?

Comment: Got a few good example [here][1]. Looks like a similar question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136699/setting-the-default-tab-when-using-storyboards

Comment: did not work with me

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

A selected index of 2 will select your third tab.

It's to put in the viewDidAppear if you first ViewController.