# Xcode: How can I change the "Default" Tab in a TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I've got an iOS App with a `TabBarController` in the `MainStoryboard`. The Tab Bar works fine but I have 5 Tabs, and now the Tab which is selected by default is the first one, but I want the middle one (in that case the 3rd --> Index:2) to be selected by default.

I've found an answer here on stack**overflow** ([Setting the default tab when using storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136699/setting-the-default-tab-when-using-storyboards#answer-30321467)), but for some reason its not working for me.
How can I manage that instead?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: there are a lot of option in that question goes through to get it done also is your tababarcontroller the initilaviewcontroller?

Comment: Can you add your code how you did it? If you change index before its viewControllers are set, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

set the selectedIndex of the tabBarController.

```
 var Launching = true
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
         if Launching == true {
             Launching = false
             self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2 // 3th tab
         }
    }
```

I hope it will works for you ... :)

Comment: I'm very new to coding for Apple. Where should I put this code?

Comment: add this code into your viewcontroller 's  swift file